# Looking to do transitions between iframes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="./css/global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<iframe id='sequencing' src='' ></iframe>

<script>
var URLs = 
[
"https://www.google.com/",
"https://www.youtube.com/",
"https://letterboxd.com/"
];
var currURL = 0;

function cycle() {
    currURL = (currURL + 1) % URLs.length;
    document.getElementById("sequencing").src = URLs[currURL];
    setTimeout(cycle, 5000);
}

cycle();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do a crossfade between various urls in a array that act as iframes. I don't want there to be a brief loading period between the sites, however, I want them to be refreshed each time they switch, how might I add a smooth crossfade between sources?

Comment: Why use iframes instead of divs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that with a single `<iframe>` element. To have a cross-fade between two URLs you need two iframes, so while one fades in the previous can fade out.

Actually it's not too hard though - you just need to group two iframes inside a `<div>` and layer them on-top each other. Now it's as simple as moving the active iframe to the foreground - by changing its z-index - fade it in and fade the second iframe out. You just have to make sure that all this happens as soon as the URL has successfully loaded into the iframe. The fading can be done using a CSS keyframe animation.

Here's an example:

```js
var URLs = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/7/256/160",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/11/128/80",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/76/64/40",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/1/32/20"
];
var currURL = 0;
var activeIFrame = document.getElementById("iFrameA");
var oldIFrame = document.getElementById("iFrameB");
var temp;

function cycle() {
  currURL = (currURL + 1) % URLs.length;
  activeIFrame.src = URLs[currURL];
  activeIFrame.onload = function() {
    activeIFrame.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    activeIFrame.classList.remove("fadeOut");
    activeIFrame.classList.add("fadeIn");
    oldIFrame.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    oldIFrame.classList.remove("fadeOut");
    oldIFrame.classList.add("fadeOut");
    activeIFrame.style.zIndex = "2";
    oldIFrame.style.zIndex = "1";
    temp = activeIFrame;
    activeIFrame = oldIFrame;
    oldIFrame = temp;
    setTimeout(cycle, 5000);
  }
}

cycle();
```

```css
@keyframes in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#iFrameA,
#iFrameB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: in 2s;
}

.fadeOut {
  animation: out 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <iframe id='iFrameA' src=''></iframe>
  <iframe id='iFrameB' src=''></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah good catch @Maksymilian Rago. That seems to happen because the opacity of a disappearing element jumps back to 1 after the animation finishes. I didn't see it because the foremost active element was covering it completely. I've fixed my code above!